# How to simulate app restart in instrument test?

Tags: android, android-testing

I want to write a test for persistent storage. The implementation details can change, for example, the code can switch from `SharedPreferences` to file-based storage or `sqlite`, but an in memory only data structure should NOT work (because it might be forgotten between activity restarts).

I want to add a automation test for this behavior, **how should I stimulate app restart?**

Answer (score 0):

[Lifecycle Testing with Robotium: Killing and Restarting Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096491/lifecycle-testing-with-robotium-killing-and-restarting-activity) might work for you.

You can *restart a stopped activity* using

```
launchActivity("com.testRestart", testactivity.class, null);
```

and *stop the activity* (using Robotium) with

```
solo.goBack();
```